# Arcgis 10.1 Archydro tools, converting RasterToPolygon How can I solve: ERROR 000732: Input Table:

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, watershed, arc-hydro, error-000732

I´m using arcgis 10.1 and Archydro tools. During the Catchment Polygon Processing, one of the steps used to define the watershed limits, I get the folowing error:

```
Executing: CatchmentPolyProcessing Cat "C:\Users\ja007\Desktop\Catchment Polygon Processing\Catchment"
Start Time: Mon Jul 06 12:28:54 2015
Converting grid to polygons...
Executing: RasterToPolygon "C:\Users\ja007\Desktop\catchment grid delineation\cat" C:\Users\ja007\AppData\Local\Temp\arcB34\AH20150706122854\AHTemp.gdb\tmpFB3B NO_SIMPLIFY VALUE
Start Time: Mon Jul 06 12:28:56 2015
Succeeded at Mon Jul 06 12:35:29 2015 (Elapsed Time: 6 minutes 32 seconds)
Dissolving catchments...
Executing: Dissolve C:\Users\ja007\AppData\Local\Temp\arcB34\AH20150706122854\AHTemp.gdb\tmpFB3B "C:\Users\ja007\Desktop\Catchment Polygon Processing\Catchment.shp" gridcode # MULTI_PART DISSOLVE_LINES
Start Time: Mon Jul 06 12:35:29 2015
Sorting Attributes...
Dissolving...
Succeeded at Mon Jul 06 13:20:08 2015 (Elapsed Time: 44 minutes 38 seconds)
Executing: AddField "C:\Users\ja007\Desktop\Catchment Polygon Processing\Catchment" HydroID LONG # # # HydroID NULLABLE NON_REQUIRED #
Start Time: Mon Jul 06 13:21:25 2015
Failed to execute. Parameters are not valid.
ERROR 000732: Input Table: Dataset C:\Users\ja007\Desktop\Catchment Polygon Processing\Catchment does not exist or is not supported
Failed to execute (AddField).
Failed at Mon Jul 06 13:21:25 2015 (Elapsed Time: 0,00 seconds)
AddFieldGPerror : System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x80004005): Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component.
   at ESRI.ArcGIS.Geoprocessing.GeoProcessorClass.Execute(String Name, IVariantArray ipValues, ITrackCancel pTrackCancel)
   at ESRI.APWR.ApHydro.GDBHelper.AddFieldGP(ApLayer apLayer, String fieldTag, String& exMessage) in C:\Builds\HydroSolutions\10.3_ArcHydro\Sources\ArcHydroTools\src\ApHydro\GDBHelper.vb:line 1339
Failed to execute (CatchmentPolyProcessing).
Failed at Mon Jul 06 13:21:25 2015 (Elapsed Time: 52 minutes 30 seconds)
```

How can I can solve this? Is this a processing limitation? I´m considering a huge área 1.246.700 km².

Comment: See this video may help you in your problem https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DK34C7QScRU&feature=youtu.be

Answer (score 1):

It appears "C:\Users\ja007\Desktop\Catchment Polygon Processing\Catchment" either doesn't exist or is not a valid input. Are you missing a file extension? It looks like a previous tool was processing "C:\Users\ja007\Desktop\Catchment Polygon Processing\Catchment.shp", so I'm assuming you forgot the .shp extension.

Comment: the raster is a valid input...the .shp extention is created by arcgis.

Comment: AddField is the tool that is failing. Are you trying to add a field to a raster?

Comment: No but I have found the problema.I have changed the pathway to C:\...\Default.gdb\Layers\Catchment, and it works...thank you